# OCaml with Threads

Tags: 12.04, programming

I already have the OCaml language working in my Ubuntu 12.04 installation, but I don't believe that it comes with the threads library. Does anyone know I can get threads working?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, so if anyone else is having this problem read on:

NOTE: This only allows thread compatibility in a top-level. Open Terminal and enter the following command:

`ocamlmktop -thread unix.cma threads.cma -o ocaml_threads`

and then to start a top-level with threads:

`./ocaml_threads -I +threads`